# Replace a string in MySQL using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have a database for my eCommerce site, I am looking to remove the a the category out of the products field. I can do it manually using:

```
UPDATE  `master_database`.`products` 
SET  `product_name` =  'Xperia Z' 
WHERE  `products`.`product_id` =5107;
```

So I've removed the word "Sony" out like this but how would I remove "Sony" out of all of the rows that have them in the products table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
UPDATE `master_database.products` 
SET    `product_name` = REPLACE (`product_name`, 'Sony ', '')
```